# How to disable panorama for Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, ux

So not only do I not use Panorama, but it is actually getting in my way too often when I open it by mistake, and frequently I find that I have tabs open that I don't want open and yet have been open for a looong ass time because I didn't know that they were there..

So my question is how do I disable panorama for Firefox??

Comment: Can you please specify which Firefox version?  I'm not familiar with the Panorama feature, but I'm only running 3.6.

Comment: It used to be called Tab Candy – been around since last July in 4.

Answer (score 2):

Well..you can't disable it. One can however, disable/modify the CTRL+E key combination using the [Keyconfig](http://files.bluefang-logic.com/firefox/keyconfig.xpi) extension. You can remove the toolbar button by customizing the toolbar.

One can press Ctrl+E a second time to close the Panorama window which is a workaround, not a real solution, IMO.